# How to print DDL command in Apache Derby

Tags: derby

In Apache Derby using the embedded ij command client, what should be the statement to execute to
generate a DDL for a particular object say a table?

I tried it with this one.

```
ij> describe client;
```

But this does show only the structure of the table and not the DDL.  I wnat it to be printed on the console.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, you will need to use a GUI SQL client.

This wiki page lists several tools which are known to work with Derby:

http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UsesOfDerby#GUI_Tools

Answer (score 1):

You might try dblook: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/tools/ctoolsdblook.html